# julia: pyplot add point

Tags: plot, julia

How can I add a single point to an existing plot with `pyplot`?

For example, I'm plotting a shifted `sin` curve over $[0,2\pi]$ with the below

```
Pkg.add("PyPlot")
using PyPlot
r1 = 0; r2 = 2*pi
N = 100
t = collect(r1:(r2-r1)/N:r2)
fig, ax = subplots()
ax[:plot](t, 1+sin(t), 
      linewidth=2.0, color="red",linestyle="--",label="constraint")
```

and I want to add a blue point at the minimum. How can I do this?

Comment: You can do `ax[:scatter](1.5π,0, color="blue")` or if you want to find a minimum in a sequence `s = 1+sin(t); pos = findfirst(x -> x == minimum(s), s); ax[:scatter](t[pos],s[pos], color="blue")`.

Comment: Actually using `indmin` instead of `findfirst` is cleaner.